# Migrating from Subversion to TFS 2013

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Can anyone suggest way to Migrating from Subversion to TFS 2013? Do I need to use a Paid Software tools for this?

I have tried the following since I access my svn through file(file://ABCServer/SVN_Source) system it doesnt support.

https://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 3):

A tip migration (i.e. no history) is the simplest, but I'll answer based on wanting to keep history.

You have 2 choices, you can migrate to a git repository or you can migrate to a TFVC repository.

Migrating to git hosted in TFS might be the easiest option. There are plenty of free tools such as git-svn tool and subgit that will help in migrating Subversion to a git repository. Once you've created the git repository locally you can then push it to the server and it's "job done".

If you want to migrate the repository to TFVC then you're probably looking at commercial tool if you want to do it in one step. A simpler option would be to first migrate svn to git, and go from git to TFVC using either git-tfs or git-tf.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. Remove the .svn folder at the root directory
2. Connect to the TFS server on visual studio
3. Right click solution in visual studio and click on "add solution to source control"
4. Complete the step and check in the code.

Comment: Did you get all the history of SVN?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I did a fresh commit. I am not sure on how history gets migrated

Comment: This is the correct way to migrate. History is way more hassle than its with.